# AngularJS dynamic $http authorization header

Tags: angularjs

I want my application to send a request to my backend and what I need is base authentication. I have following code:

```
myApp.factory('ApiRequest', ['$http', 'AccountService', function($http, AccountService) {

var apiURL = 'https://web.appspot.com/_ah/api/server';
var apiVer = 'v1';
var url = apiURL + '/' + apiVer;

return {
    getMessages: function(time_offset) {
        var encodedCredentials = AccountService.generateBase64Credentials();

        // $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = encodedCredentials; tried like this, but doesn't work too
        return $http.get(
            url + '/message', {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': AccountService.generateBase64Credentials()
                },
                params: {
                    recipient_id: '6305746161500160',
                    recipient_type: 'circle',
                    time_offset: time_offset ? time_offset : null
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
}]);
```

Unfortunately every time I obtain this authorization header:

```
Basic W29iamVjdCBPYmplY3RdOltvYmplY3QgT2JqZWN0XQ==
```

My function AccountService.generateBase64Credentials return string: Basic window.btoa(login:password), so Why does it work this way? How can I make it work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input to Base64 encoding is incorrect. When I have decoded the string, it is returning "[object Object]:[object Object]" (excluding double quotes). Please check the input to "window.btoa" function first.

Comment: I knew the result of decoding, but I didn't know that it may be the problem. Thank you!